# Make \vspace appear below empty \subparagraph

Tags: spacing, sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I was doing some homework in LaTeX, and I wanted to put some blank space below a subparagraph heading so that I could draw a diagram in after printing it out. For the subparagraphs where I had content before the spacing, using \vspace worked fine to insert blank space. However, when I tried putting a \vspace directly after a \subparagraph, like

```
\subparagraph{some homework section}
\vspace{2in}
```

the vertical space rendered above the subparagraph heading rather than below it. I temporarily fixed it by adding a \quad before the \vspace, but that feels hacky and I would rather know the reason it's exhibiting this behavior. This occurred with both `\vspace` and `\vspace*`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina How do I do that? Edit: Oh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `\vspace` in vertical mode, `\vspace` simply executes a `\vskip` (in vertical mode) and this produces the undesired effect; just make sure to leave vertical mode using, for example, `\mbox{}` or `\leavevmode` directly (your `\quad` also causes to leave vertical mode):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

a
\subparagraph{some homework section}
\leavevmode\vspace{2in}

b

\end{document}
```

[image]