# Using vspace, with spacing?

Tags: spacing

When I use the vspace command it won't work unless I put a new, empty line before and after the command. Is this normal? If it is, why is that? Why does it require spacing around the command?

Comment: It is not normal if you really need to put an empty line *before* it. Needing one afterwards is a different matter.

Comment: It does work (most of the code for `\vspace` is explicitly dealing with the case when it does _not_ have a blank line before it), it may be that you are expecting it to do something else, but in that case it would be more helpful if you said what you expected it to do.

Comment: covers the same territory: [Non-uniform white spacing with \vspace](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134899/579)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\vspace` only takes effect when LaTeX creates a line break or a new paragraph. I think more technically, `\vspace` only has effect when LaTeX is in vertical mode.  If LaTeX is not currently in vertical mode, LaTeX *saves* the `\vspace` until next time it enters vertical mode.

So for example I can write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

  Alice was beginning \vspace{2ex} to get very tired of sitting by her sister on
  the bank, and of having nothing to do. Once or twice she had peeped
  into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or
  conversations in it, ``and what is the use of a book,'' thought
  Alice, ``without pictures or conversations?''

\end{document}
```

which results in

> [image]

If I want to force the `\vspace` at the point where I place it, I must start a newline there also:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

  Alice was beginning \vspace{2ex}\newline to get very tired of sitting by her sister on
  the bank, and of having nothing to do. Once or twice she had peeped
  into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or
  conversations in it, ``and what is the use of a book,'' thought
  Alice, ``without pictures or conversations?''

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Alternatively you can start a new paragraph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

  Alice was beginning \vspace{2ex}

  \noindent
  to get very tired of sitting by her sister on
  the bank, and of having nothing to do. Once or twice she had peeped
  into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or
  conversations in it, ``and what is the use of a book,'' thought
  Alice, ``without pictures or conversations?''

\end{document}
```

> [image]

These last two examples may look very similar, but the effects could be different if you've set `\parskip` to a non-zero value, which is generally discouraged.

Comment: If `\vspace` only has effect when LaTeX is in vertical mode, why don't you put `\newline` or `\par` or a blank line before `\vspace` rather than after `\vspace`? :-) Because intuitively the mode switching should happen before `\vspace`.

Comment: @StiffJokes `\newline` / `\\ ` don't start vertical mode, they just put a negative penalty into the horizontal list so that a linebreak will be added at that point when th eparagraph is broken into lines.

Comment: It's probably misleading to say it saves the `\vspace` : the vspace is executed (and any macros in its argument fully expanded) at the point it appeares, the resulting space though goes into a vadjust node that will be inserted after the current line. so `\setlength\foo{3pt}\vspace{\foo}\setlength\foo{10pt} zzzzzz\par} then 3pt not 10pt will be added